Docker elasticsearch FileSystemException - Not a directory
I'm very new to Docker as well as ElasticSearch. I was following a tutorial and used this docker compose file to install ElasticSearch:
version: "4.6"
services:
  es01:
    image: "docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-oss:7.10.2"
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
    environment:
      node.name: es01
      discovery.seed_hosts: es01,es02,es03
      cluster.initial_master_nodes: es01,es02,es03
      cluster.name: mycluster
      bootstrap.memory_lock: "true"
      ES_JAVA_OPTS: -Xms256m -Xmx256m
    volumes:
      - "es-data-es01:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "curl http://localhost:9200"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 120
  es02:
    image: "docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-oss:7.10.2"
    ports:
      - "9201:9200"
      - "9301:9300"
    environment:
      node.name: es02
      discovery.seed_hosts: es01,es02,es03
      cluster.initial_master_nodes: es01,es02,es03
      cluster.name: mycluster
      bootstrap.memory_lock: "true"
      ES_JAVA_OPTS: -Xms256m -Xmx256m
    volumes:
      - "es-data-es02:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "curl http://localhost:9200"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 120
  es03:
    image: "docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-oss:7.10.2"
    ports:
      - "9202:9200"
      - "9303:9300"
    environment:
      node.name: es03
      discovery.seed_hosts: es01,es02,es03
      cluster.initial_master_nodes: es01,es02,es03
      cluster.name: mycluster
      bootstrap.memory_lock: "true"
      ES_JAVA_OPTS: -Xms256m -Xmx256m
    volumes:
      - "es-data-es03:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "curl http://localhost:9200"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 120
  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana-oss:7.10.2
    depends_on:
      es01:
        condition: service_healthy
      es02:
        condition: service_healthy
      es03:
        condition: service_healthy
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    environment:
      - 'ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=["http://es01:9200","http://es02:9200","http://es03:9200"]'
volumes:
  es-data-es01:
  es-data-es02:
  es-data-es03:


I get a FileSystemException error when I run docker compose:

api-es03-1    | "stacktrace": ["org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.StartupException: ElasticsearchException[failed to bind service]; nested: FileSystemException[/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/nodes/0: Not a directory];",
api-es03-1    | "at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:174) ~[elasticsearch-7.10.2.jar:7.10.2]",
api-es03-1    | "at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:161) ~[elasticsearch-7.10.2.jar:7.10.2]",
api-es03-1    | "at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:86) ~[elasticsearch-7.10.2.jar:7.10.2]",
api-es03-1    | "at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:127) ~[elasticsearch-cli-7.10.2.jar:7.10.2]",
api-es03-1    | "at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90) ~[elasticsearch-cli-7.10.2.jar:7.10.2]",
api-es03-1    | "at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:126) ~[elasticsearch-7.10.2.jar:7.10.2]",
api-es03-1    | "at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:92) ~[elasticsearch-7.10.2.jar:7.10.2]",
api-es03-1    | "Caused by: org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: failed to bind service",
api-es03-1    | "at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:729) ~[elasticsearch-7.10.2.jar:7.10.2]",
api-es03-1    | "at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:289) ~[elasticsearch-7.10.2.jar:7.10.2]",
api-es03-1    | "at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$5.<init>(Bootstrap.java:227) ~[elasticsearch-7.10.2.jar:7.10.2]",
api-es03-1    | "at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:227) ~[elasticsearch-7.10.2.jar:7.10.2]",
api-es03-1    | "at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:393) ~[elasticsearch-7.10.2.jar:7.10.2]",
api-es03-1    | "at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:170) ~[elasticsearch-7.10.2.jar:7.10.2]",
api-es03-1    | "... 6 more",


I was expecting the elastic search server to run smoothly.

This is clearly a mounting path problem.
To put it simply, the containers and the host machine should exchange data. This is done by:
anonymous volume: Destroyed when container stopped, not permanent.
named volume: You name it but can not specify the path. You can find the path by:
docker volume inspect volume-name

bind-mount: Almost the same as named volume but you specify the path.
And the place where you exchange your data in container, for example:
es-data-es03:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data

This means, there should be a data exchange between your host on this file: es-data-es03 and in the container itself: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
This assures even if your container shuts down, you have the data at es-data-es03.
But your errors indicates:

FileSystemException[/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/nodes/0: Not a directory]

which means you it expects a folder not a file. I checked your mounts, they are all the same. There can be a corrupt volume file somewhere. I would remove all containers and volumes and start from scratch.
docker ps -a                   // Show all active and inactive containers
docker rm container-name       // Remove container one by one
docker volume ls               // Show all volumes
docker volume prune            // Remove all unused volumes
docker volume rm volume-name   // Remove volume by name

If the container starts, you can go into the container with:
docker exec -it container-name bash

and check the files. But it should be running.
